# Changing SIM card reset/lost stored google password

Tags: 2.2-froyo, htc-desire-z, google-account

For troubleshooting reasons, T-Mobile gave me a new SIM card.

After swapping the card, my phone did not know the google password, I had to enter it again.

I tried to research the linkage (is it stored in the SIM, does the phone reset the stored password for a new SIM, etc.)

I am pretty sure that it does not happen on removal of the SIM, because I had taking my old SIM out several times, to ferry data from my old handset.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's linked to the SIM for security, but not stored on the SIM (so you can take it out).

Comment: I just changed the sim card in my phone and got the "sign in error" when the phone forgets the password, but then when I put my original sim back in, it didn't remember my sim card. I wonder if the password is reset when a new sim card is inserted.

Comment: @pydave It is, yes.